# Should I Include a Disclaimer in My Android Application (Speech Disabled App)

Tags: android, android-studio

I created an application which I haven't uploaded to play store. The application is meant to aid individuals with speech disability to communicate. So the app includes a bunch of phrases. the user will press a button, and the app will speak the phrase using text 2 speech. So that's the core function of the app. My concern is: should I include a disclaimer for the user to accept when they first open the app. The reason I ask this, is because it is hard to assume responsibility if someone misuse the app or they don't know how to work with the app and they don't get assistance as soon as they need it. So that's basically my question. I think is more of a legal question about the term of use of an application. If someone with knowledge in this area can assist? and if I include a disclaimer where could I find one thanks?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a programming question.  Ask a lawyer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not a lawyer but I would include an "End User License Agreement" or "EULA" that is shown on first use and then is available from the Menu to read again.

This is try and protect yourself from any claims against you and or somebody else profiting from your work.

There is a blog at https://www.termsfeed.com/blog/sample-eula-template/ about EULA's

They offer tools to generate EULA's as well.

I would also record in shared preferences when it is accepted, so you don't display it again at startup.

I would also record which version was accepted in shared preferences so that you can up the version and show the EULA again.

I would offer the ability not to accept the EULA, at which point you close your App.

While on the subject to Licenses it is also good practise to display Third Party Licenses from a Menu as well (You will most likely be using some Third Party Software with Licenses that need displaying)